# I am not able to view my home folder or any files in my system

Tags: package-management, directory

Let me confess, I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.
I was actually trying to remove a broken package of a screensaver I tried to download via Synaptic Package Manager. Because of this broken package I was not able to install any new programs or packages. So desperately I tries it using Synaptic. Some how to error sign in the top right corner of my system got removed, but now I am not able to see my home folder or even able to access any of the files. When I tried to go to folder through transmission, by opening a downloaded file, this is what is showing....

[image]

Some kind of pie chart showing disk usage...

I don't know if I accidentally deleted my home folder or if its hidden. 
Please help me with this. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I think all my datas are there because in the graph I mentioned earlier it showing all my files and folders with the correct memory used..